# react-native: reset checkbox state when other checkbox is pressed

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have multiple checkboxes that user can change state. But I want only one check box to be active. How can I reset other checkboxes state when another check box is selected?

This is my code:

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'Kevin ',
    id:0,
    checked:false
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    id:1,
    checked:false
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    id:2,
    checked:false
  },
]


export default class SelectPetScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
      list: list
    }
  }

keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString()

checkThisBox=(itemID)=>{
   let list = this.state.list
   list[itemID].checked =! list[itemID].checked
   this.setState({list:list})
}

renderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <TouchableHighlight
  onPress={() => this.checkThisBox(item.id)}>
  <ListItem
    containerStyle={styles.cardStyle}
    title={<View><Text>{item.name}</Text></View>}
    rightAvatar={
      <View style={{marginRight:20}}>
      <CheckBox
        checked={this.state.list[item.id].checked}
        onPress={() => this.checkThisBox(item.id)}
      />
      </View>
    }
    >
    </ListItem>
    </TouchableHighlight>

)
  render() {
  return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList
               keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
               data={this.state.list}
               renderItem={this.renderItem}
               extraData={this.state}
             />
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
    )
  };
}
```

Is it possible to reset checkbox's previous state when other checkbox is selected? Any advise or comments would be really appreciated!

Comment: assume that the first checkbox is actived, what is the behavior if user click the first check box ? is it still actived

Comment: No i want it to be not active

Comment: then active the last checked checkbox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
checkThisBox= itemID => {
  const updatedList = this.state.list.map( item => item.id === itemId ?  {...item, checked:true} :  {...item, checked:false} );
  this.setState({list:updatedList})
}
```

try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset all checkboxes's state and after that update the new one:

```
checkThisBox=(itemID)=>{
    let list = this.state.list
    list.forEach(option => {
        option.checked = false
    });
    list[itemID].checked = true
    this.setState({ list: list })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you're trying to do is that you have a list of items, each item in the list has a checkbox and what happens is when you press one checkbox, all checkboxes get updated.
Try this solution:

```
checkThisBox=(value, index)=>{
  const tempData = this.state.list;
  tempData[index].checked= value;
  this.setState({ 
    list: tempData, 
  });
}
```

And then add `extraData={this.state}` prop in your flatlist in order to update the flatlist otherwise it won't update your list.

Hope it helps..!